# Websockets and RX

Tags: concurrency, websocket, system.reactive

The [prototype for WCF Websocket](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2010/12/websockets-wcf-service-silverlight-and.html) limits the number of concurrent connections. Even so, I'd like to play a bit with multiple clients. Probably Rx could be used to handle subscriptions. How would you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think WCF allows you to change the maximum number of connections: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.maxconnections.aspx

If you're using NetTcpBinding then you can just set the maximum number of connections:

```
int maxNumConnections = 100; 

// Set the maximum number of connections for your tcp binding
binding.MaxConnections = maxNumConnections;
```